# How do I import multiple tif images and save it as one tiff file with skimage or gdal in python?

Tags: python, gdal, numpy, matplotlib, scipy.spatial

I am new to Python and I am trying to import multiple tif images so that I can do image processing with skimage. I want to do image processing on a Landsat image to define linear features for a project that has to be in before the end of the year.

I am using a Landsat 8 image that consists of 11 bands (individual tif files), a bqa file and a `metadata.txt` file.

I can import a band one by one, but I don't know how to stack the bands into one tiff file that also contains the metadata.txt file.

This is what I have done so far:

```
import os filename = os.path.join('path', 'band1.TIF') 
import skimage from skimage 
import io bandone = io.imread(filename)
```

So my image has been successfully imported as converted to a nparray.
I have to repeat this to import all the bands.

What is the best way to save these bands together?

```
skimage.external.tifffile.imsave('file, data, **kwargs) ?
skimage.io.imsave(fname, arr, plugin=None, **plugin_args) ?
TiffWriter ?
```

Or should I do something else completely?

Please elaborate on the details (such as how to define `**kwargs` for instance).

Comment: Did you try gdal_merge.py? www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html

Comment: With option `-separate`. You need to convert all bands to same resolution first.

Comment: Hey Zoltan, no I havn't. I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: When I convert all the bands to the same resolution, isn't that going to affect the quality of my data?

Comment: How do I assign directories to all my image files? When I use $ gdalinfo can only take one file at a time. So then $ gdal_merge.py -o out.tif inbandone.TIF works but only for bandone. How do I get gdal_merge.py -o out.tif in1.tif in2.tif inn.tif to work?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy with gdal_array.SaveArray:

```
from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array

# open one of the landsat images to use as a prototype to get projection info from
ds = gdal.Open("landsat_band.tif")

# list of np arrays to stack
bands = [band1_arr, band2_arr, band3_arr ... ]

# stack arrays
stack = np.array(bands)

# save as output.tif
gdal_array.SaveArray(stack, "output.tif", "gtiff", prototype=ds)

ds = None
```